# How do I determine the rarity/level of a unique magic item or spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, homebrew

I am planning on making several new magic items and spells, as well as allowing my players to make some.

As far as I know, the rules in the DMG only describe the relevant spell levels for spells that involve damage, in its table. For magic items that don’t act like spells, for example: a ladder that can expand or compress down, I haven't found any way to assign them a rarity.

How do I determine the rarity or spell level for unique effects that don't do damage? I will allow content outside of the main books to be used in the answer.

Comment: @AllanMills See [this FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/321) for why your comment was removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## Look for an equivalent spell or existing magic item as guidance

Odds are, there is a similar out there in either function or power. Function is obviously much easier to find, but looking at the utility of the item you are creating and comparing it against the utility of existing items is your best place to figure out the rarity.

Odds are there may or may not be a 1:1 match, but there is likely something similar that can help.

### Ask here!

When in doubt, once you've got a specific homebrew item and you're not sure if there is an equivalent, ask us here! There's a lot of stackizens and while you or others may not have heard of equivalent or near-equivalent item X, someone else may have or see a connection of equivalence that you haven't seen.